# updating gradle in android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, native

good evening everyone.
i've updated android studio to chipmunk version, and the ide suggested me to update gradle to version 7.3.3 and I did.

here is gradle-wrapper.properties

```
#Tue Aug 30 18:40:21 EEST 2022
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

and here is build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

when I sync get this error

```
Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.2.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:
```

I've tried to delete the gradle and redownload it again but it did not work

what should I do ?
hope you can help me